# Parse Time vs. Execution Time in batch file

Tags: batch-file, terminology

I am trying to learn MS Batch, and I was specifically trying to understand the `setlocal` and the `enabledelayedexpression` aspects, when I came across vocabulary I did not understand: **execution time** and **parse time**

Answer (score 5):

The parser has different phases, when parsing a single line.
So the percent expressions are all expand when a line or block is parsed, before the line (or any line in a block) is executed.

So at execution time they can't change anymore.

```
set var=origin
echo #1 %var%
(
  set var=new value
  echo #2 %var%
)
echo #3 %var%
```

It outputs

```
#1 origin
#2 origin
#3 new value
```

As at parse time #2 will be expanded to `origin` before any line of the block is executed.
So you can see the new value just after the block at #3.

In contrast, delayed expansion is expanded for each line just before the line is executed.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set var=origin
echo #1 %var%, !var!
(
  set var=new value
  echo #2 %var%, !var!
)
echo #3 %var%, !var!
```

Output

```
#1 origin, origin
#2 origin, new value
#3 new value, new value
```

Now at #2 you see two different expansions for the same variable, as %var% is expanded when the block is parsed, but `!var!` is expanded after the line `set var=new value` was executed.

More details about the batch parser at [SO: How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133)