# Print variable in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to print a variable in parenthesised code which is assigned a value using other variable in batch file.

Here is my code

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion
CALL initialize
CALL fun
:fun (
 @echo off
 Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 Set "SOMEVAR=!OTHERVAR!"
 ECHO ..%SOMEVAR%
 EXIT /B 0
)
:initialize (
 set SOMEVAR=somevalue
EXIT /B 0
)
```

The output is just

```
..
```

How do i fix it so that i can assign value to somevar?

Edit1: If i now try to print in following way it does its job

```
ECHO ..!SOMEVAR!
```

But my script uses lot of %SOMEVAR%. Does that mean i need to change them all?

> Note: Othervar is initialzed in other function and it does show proper value if it is echoed.

Comment: Your code doesn't show how that `OTHERVAR` is assigned (it's empty by default naturally). Generally it should work as is even with quotes.

Comment: @wOxxOm: actully its just a snippet from actual code which i am trying to edit. All the values are previously initialized.

Comment: Well, your code works as expected here if I add a simple initializer or assign OTHERVAR in a loop. Divide your batch file and conquer the problem.

Comment: Where is `OTHERVAR` echoed? within a different `setlocal`/`endlocal` block maybe, could that be? if so, type `setlocal /?` and `endlocal /?` and consult the help messages...

Comment: @aschipfl: If i add "echo !OTHERVAR!" Just after setlocal statement it shows the correct value which in my case would be c:\xyz

Comment: Okay... I guess your code snippet is part of a compound statement, that is, a code portion enclosed in parantheses `()` -- right??; such is considered as a single command line; variables enclosed in `%%` are expanded to their values at parsing time, that is, when the line of code is _read_; so `set` works fine, but the expansion of `%SOMEVAR%` happens earlier...

Comment: How about commenting out or removing `@echo off` to see if any helpful information appears?

Comment: @aschipfl: you are right. My code is in parenthesis so i guess i need to change all my %SOMEVAR% expansions to !SOMEVAR!.
Can you please put that as an answer so that i can check it as correct one?

Comment: Putting it as an answer makes only sense if you update your question so that the parenthesised code is comprised... currently it would rather cause confusion than help other programmers...

Comment: how does the q sounds now?

Comment: You have the classical [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324354/windows-batch-files-what-is-variable-expansion-and-what-does-enabledelayedexpa/25328044#25328044) problem...

Comment: @Aacini: yep i am done with the problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code portion containing `echo %SOMEVAR%` is in between parenthesis, the variable is expanded before being set (consult [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324354/windows-batch-files-what-is-variable-expansion-and-what-does-enabledelayedexpa/25328044#25328044) for a good explanation).

There are the following options to avoid that:

1. to expand it like `!SOMEVAR!` (delayed expansion), or
2. to avoid the parenthesis:

   ```
   @echo off
   SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
   CALL initialize
   CALL fun
   exit /B

   :fun
   Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   Set "SOMEVAR=!OTHERVAR!"
   ECHO ..%SOMEVAR%
   EXIT /B 0

   :initialize
   set SOMEVAR=somevalue
   EXIT /B 0
   ```

   Note the additional `exit /B` in the above code snippet after the `call` statements, which prevents from falling into the code below unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work any closer to your expectations? Note that SOMEVAR will not be returned to your shell environment unless an ENDLOCAL block is used.

```
C:>set OTHERVAR=0123456789

C:>type g2.bat
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion

CALL:initialize
CALL:fun
EXIT /B 0

:fun (
    rem @echo off
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "SOMEVAR=!OTHERVAR!"
    ECHO ..%SOMEVAR%
    GOTO :EOF
)

:initialize (
    set SOMEVAR=somevalue
    GOTO :EOF
)

C:>g2.bat
..0123456789
```

Comment: Hi @Paul: it works when its the only thing in file but my code is in parenthesis so %% wont work since those are evaluated at compile time as opposed to !! which is done at run time. So there is no option than to use !! for all my usage :D. Anyways thanks for trying that out!