# Missing Operator Error In Batch Game

Tags: batch-file

```
:teattack1
set /a health-=!monsterdmg! # It said missing operator here
pause
set /a monsterhealth-=!playerdmg! # And Here
pause
if "!monsterhealth!" == lss 0 goto tewin
pause
goto testencounter
pause
goto encountermenu
```

I keep getting Missing Operator

I serched how to fix it but did not find anything

Comment: Did you tried to output your variables before? `echo health=!health! monster=!monsterdmg!`

Comment: What is `== lss` supposed to be doing? You only need one or the other. Also, you don't need quotes on the left side if you're going to use `lss`.

Comment: It's also a good idea to enable `ECHO ON` just before the problem occurs and show the output in your question

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
```

to your script to allow the use of `!` 
[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324354/windows-batch-files-what-is-variable-expansion-and-what-does-enabledelayedexpa) for an overview of what this does and why its needed

Comment: I hope that he has already enabled delayed expansion, at least. But you could be right!

Comment: @MineCakePvP - Well then `!monsterdmg!` hasn't been set correctly.

Comment: That would give a missing operand error, not missing operator. @MineCakePvP do you have the # comments in your code? Make sure no comments are on the same line as these set operations.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt window, enter `set /?` and read all output help pages carefully.

It is explained that when using **set** for an arithmetic expression, i.e. `set /A`, then variable names can be specified directly without expansion. Windows command processor interprets automatically each string not being a number or an operator as name of a variable and access the **current** variable value on evaluating the arithmetic expression.

Next run in command prompt window `if /?` and read again all output help pages carefully.

The line

```
if "!monsterhealth!" == lss 0 goto tewin
```

is definitely invalid as it contains the operator `==` and the operator `lss` which of course can't work.

This improved code is with all coding mistakes fixed.

```
:teattack1
set /a health-=monsterdmg
pause
set /a monsterhealth-=playerdmg
pause
if %monsterhealth% LEQ 0 goto tewin
pause
goto testencounter
pause
goto encountermenu
```

However, the environment variables `health`, `monsterdmg`, `monsterhealth` and `playerdmg` should all exist and have an integer value assigned as otherwise Windows command interpreter uses value `0` for each variable making the code not really useful.