# Why does a SET not take hold in an ECHO command in the same line?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am new to Windows 10 64-bit and start Command Prompt and type the following (set variable and echo it in same line):

```
H:\>set a="hello" & echo %a%
%a%

H:\>set a="hello" & echo %a%
"hello"
```

Why do I not see "hello" the first time I echo'ed it?

Apologies if this a basic question, I cannot seem to have found the answer online.

Comment: First line doesn't clear `a` after `echo`. Try `set a="hello" & echo %a% & set "a="` to verify.

Comment: Start Command Prompt and type these three separated lines: `set a="one" & echo %a%`, then `set a="two" & echo %a%`, then `set a="three" & echo %a%`. Then, look for the difference of "Delayed Expansion" vs. %normal% expansion...

Comment: Related: [Example of delayed expansion in batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10558316)

Comment: [Another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324354/windows-batch-files-what-is-variable-expansion-and-what-does-enabledelayedexpa/25328044#25328044).

Comment: and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082). There must be dozens.

Comment: Thank you everyone. As I am using cmd prompt, it doesn't seem possible to use delayed expansion once the prompt has opened. I have to either relaunch it with /v flag (`cmd /v`) or simply invoke batch files that have delayed expansion enabled using  `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the line will be evaluated before the `set` command, so on the first run `%a%` will be passed as is (a string `"%a%"` because `a` was **not** present).

After evaluating variables the first line will look like:

```
set a="hello" & echo %a%
```

The second line will be evaluated as:

```
set a="hello" & echo hello
```

before running any commands.