# Rename a file with two variables in windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to rename a file with two variables in a batch file. I have file with name `foo_hello.txt` and I want to rename it to `foo_20_hello_50.txt`.

20 and 50 are two different #define in the same header file.

I was successful in renaming it with one variable.

```
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('FINDSTR /C:"Place" ..\header.h') do ren foo_hello.txt foo_hello_%%i.txt
```

but I am not sure how to add the other variable in the filename.

Comment: That's not really Bash, is it?

Comment: This looks like cmd, not bash.

Comment: You're confusing Windows batch files with bash.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324354/windows-batch-files-what-is-variable-expansion-and-what-does-enabledelayedexpa) explains all you want to know.

Comment: Might be easier to answer were you to tell us how the "50" and "25" are derived.

Comment: You have not explained where the `50` and `20` come from, so we can only guess: `for /f "tokens=3,4" %%i in ("One Place 50 20") do ren foo_hello.txt foo_%%j_hello_%%i.txt`

Comment: Place  = 50 and Watch = 20 are two different variables in the same file with which I need to update the file name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question have several missing details: What is the format of the input file? Is there just one line with each value? What value is placed first in the file? or, they may come in any order...

The Batch file below *assume* that the values are placed in "Place" then "Watch" order. If this is not true, the code needs to be changed...

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "Place="
for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('FINDSTR "Place Watch" header.h') do (
   if not defined Place (
      set "Place=%%i"
   ) else (
      set "Watch=%%i"
   )
)

ECHO ren foo_hello.txt foo_%Watch%_hello_%Place%.txt
```

Input file:

```
First line
#define Place 50
Mid line
#define Watch 20
Last line
```

Output example:

```
ren foo_hello.txt foo_20_hello_50.txt
```