# How to echo a variable multiple times by multiplying it with another variable?

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch script and I am having trouble echoing a variable, here is the script,

```
@echo off
set num1=1
set num2=10
set /a "out=%num1%*%num2%"
echo %out%
pause`
```

The output I receive is 10 which makes sense but I want it to echo 'num1' ten times instead of multiplying 'num1' by 'num2'. So I want the output to be 1111111111.

Also I don't want to loop the command 10 times as I am putting the output into a text file with 'output>> file.txt' otherwise I will end up with this in the text file,

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
```

I want to end up with 1111111111, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set num1=1
set num2=10
SET "out="&FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%num2%) DO CALL SET "out=%%out%%%%num1%%"
echo %out%
GOTO :EOF
```

The `SET "out="` and `FOR /L %%a IN (1,1,%num2%) DO CALL SET "out=%%out%%%%num1%%"` may be on separate lines if desired. Setting `out` to *nothing* is simply a safety measure to ensure that *if* it contains a value, it's cleared first.

The `for /L` performs the `call` command `num2` times.

The `call` command executes `SET "out=%out%%num1%"` in a subprocess because each `%%` is interpreted as an escaped-% (`%` is the escape character for `%`) - "escaping" a character means turning off its special meaning.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Just to show a different method with `set /A` and a loop:

```
@echo off
set /A "num1=1,num2=10,out=0"
:loop
set /a "out*=10,out+=num1,num2-=1"
If %num2% gtr 0 goto :loop
echo %out%
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way to solve this problem, using [Delayed Expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25324354/windows-batch-files-what-is-variable-expansion-and-what-does-enabledelayedexpa/25328044#25328044).

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set num1=1
set num2=10
set "out="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%num2%) do set "out=!out!%num1%"
echo %out%
pause
```

PS - The *multiply* term is not exact in this case; perhaps "echo a variable the times indicated by another variable" be more clear...

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to print `num1` `num2` times in the same line you can do something like:

```
@echo off
set "num1=1"
set "num2=10"
(for /L %%i in (1,1,%num2%) do set /p "=%num1%" <nul
echo()>file.txt
```

The command `set /p "=%num1%" <nul` prints the text `%num1%` in the current line without the `LF` character. So `num1` gets printed `num2` times in the same line.